# error en migracion claves foraneas laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

tengo este error al migrar con una tabla ya me puse a validar campos pero no veo error y me marca lo mismo al hacerlo manualmente en mysql.

agregue estas lineas a Providers pero sigue mandando error.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('libros_prestamos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('libro_id');
        $table->foreign('libro_id', 'fk_libroprestamo_libro')->references('id')->on('libros')->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('restrict');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id', 'fk_libroprestamo_usuario')->references('id')->on('usuarios')->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('restrict');
        $table->date('fecha_prestamo');
        $table->string('prestamo_a', '100');
        $table->boolean('estado');
        $table->date('fecha_devolucion')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

**ERROR**

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `libros_prestamos` add constraint `fk_libroprestamo_usuario` foreign key (`user_id`) references `usuarios` (`id`) on delete restrict on update restrict)
```

Comment: Y que error da?

Comment: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `libros_prestamos` add constraint `fk_libroprestamo_libro` foreign key (`libro_id`) references `libros` (`id`) on delete restrict on update restrict)

Comment: sii esta es la ultima tabla al migrar

Comment: me marca lo mismo con los cambios

Comment: Checka que el motor de ambas tablas sea `InnoDB`. También que los tipos de datos de las columnas sean el mismo (`integer`, o `bigInteger`)

Comment: gracias el problema fue que id_usuario era bigInteger lo cambien a increments y no salio ningun error muchas gracias